# Absorption spectra Oxygen vs temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation, wavelength, absorption

Whilst recently commissioning a spectroscopic *Tunable diode laser* "Oxygen Analyser" on a waste-to-energy plant, I wondered how the Analyser (which fires a narrow wavelength laser across the process and measures absorption at the receiver end) differentiates between hot oxygen at $\rm 1120\ K$ and ambient temperature oxygen.

There were two measurements on the unit (cold & hot) which show independently at different wavelengths when Interrogating the absorption spectra.

My Question :

Does the wavelength of $O_2$ change as the temperature rises? I had always assumed the absorption wavelength of a gas is constant?